# Elasticsearch how to order by filter query

Tags: elasticsearch

**i have the following query the result is satisfying but the order of result not according to  filter applied.**

the order of results should be:
a1.in
a2.in
a3.in

but the results are not ordered by the filters.

my question is how i can order by the results as per the filters applied?

thanks in advance.

**Following is the query i am using**

```
post /mycity/_search?_source=meta_description,url,h1tag
{
"query": {
    "function_score":{
     "query":{
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
       "meta_description.edgegrm": {
        "query": "best restaurant",
        "prefix_length": 1,
        "max_expansions": 5,
        "slop":10,
        "minimum_should_match":"75%"

       }
    }   
     },
     "query":{
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
       "content.edgegrm": {
        "query": "best restaurant",
        "prefix_length": 1,
        "max_expansions": 5,
        "slop":10,
        "minimum_should_match":"75%"

       }
    }
     },
     "functions":[
         {
             "filter":{"term": {
            "host": "www.a1.in/city"
         }},
         "weight":100

         },
         {
             "filter":{
              "term": {
                 "host": "www.a2.in/city"
              }   
             },
             "weight":50
         },
              {
             "filter":{
              "term": {
                 "host": "www.a3.in/city"
              }   
             },
             "weight":25
         }


         ],
         "score_mode": "sum"


    }

},

"from":0,
"size":100
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting boost_mode to sum as well.

Comment: sorry for late response. your suggestion work perfectly.